# how to clear a UIView (ios)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview

I have a `searchBar` with two scope titles. When I pick one of two, I want to display some data for this category in a `UIView`.

I try to make this because the simple conclusion did not work. It works but the data is superimposed on top of each other when I saw with a scope titles.

I know about `UITableView` and `reloadData()` but I need a `UIView` because I make a cloud of tags (use label in code).

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
    searchBar.delegate = self

    checkData(data)
    if index == 0 {
        createTagsLabel(main: City)
        view.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
    else {
        createTagsLabel(main: Contractor)
        //listTags.clearsContextBeforeDrawing
    }
}

func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
    index = selectedScope
    searchBar.text = nil
    viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: Never call `viewDidLoad` yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean to remove all child views, you can use `subviews` property, like so:

```
view.subviews.forEach { $0.removeFromSuperview() }
```

But I would suggest that you remove the main view itself and initialize a new one